# Azure Functions: No such file or directory

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a Problem with my Azure Function. I use a Linux based App service Plan (B1). After deploying my Code and running the Azure function I get this Error.

```
2020-03-11T07:02:55.985 [Error] Executed 'PdfRender_dotnet_framework' (Failed, Id=52201ad7-8012-4f93-bc17-0accae6a1540)
No such file or directory
```

The strange thing about this is that I can change to this Directory in the console and in Kudu with bash/ssh. So it seems that everything was deployed fine, but why is it still showing me this error message.

I checked many times if everything was deployed right and i didn't find any issues.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCts3.png)

[image]

[Directory in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ4hI.png)

[image]

[Directory in Bash (Kudu)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU2BM.png)

[image]

[This is my function.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QRU2.png)

I also noticed that the azure function reach the code.

My Function Code.

```
 public static class dotnet_core_pdf
    {
        [FunctionName("dotnet_core_pdf")]
        public static HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext executionContext)
        {

            string name = req.Query["url"];
            log.Info(name);

            //Initialize HTML to PDF converter  
            HtmlToPdfConverter htmlConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
            WebKitConverterSettings settings = new WebKitConverterSettings();

            //Set WebKit path
            settings.WebKitPath = Path.Combine(executionContext.FunctionAppDirectory, "QtBinariesWindows");
            //Assign WebKit settings to HTML converter 
            htmlConverter.ConverterSettings = settings;

            //Convert URL to PDF 
            PdfDocument document = htmlConverter.Convert(name);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            //Save the PDF document  
            document.Save(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;

            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "HTMLToPDFAzure.pdf"
            };
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

            return response;


        }
    }
}
```

**NOTICE: I changed the folders Name, I am using .Net Core not .Net Framework**

Comment: Could you show the code you access file?

Comment: one thing I notice: You are running your Function under Linux but you seem to want to use a .NET Framework library (at least from the name it looks that way)?! This won't work as Linux Functions must be NET Core

Comment: Can you check the actual path? print the full path just before accessing the directory. You may be assuming it is wrt home directory but function must be referring with respect to runtime/bin directory.

Comment: The file path seems fine, and i am using .net core i forgot to change the folders name. Should the folder be in bin instead of wwwroot?

Comment: @GeorgeChen what do you mean by access file ? do you mean my function.json or dll?

Comment: I mean your function main code.

Comment: could the problem be related to the dll file? it tries to run the dll file from function.json. And Linux is not dll compatible.